# Terminal does not have focus on launch through a shortcut

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal

When I open terminal through application menu (top left side menu) or from dock, then terminal opens with focus on it, over all other windows. 
When I try to open terminal through a shortcut, terminal opens behind focused window.

How to make terminal be on top of other windows on launch through a shorctcut?

Comment: shortcut means from dock?

Comment: @Ravan shortcut means keyboard shortcuts, win + t

Comment: Are you sure about this behaviour ? because when I open browser over existing terminal , the win + t opens new terminal at background .

Comment: I posted answer , please let me know your problem solved or not =)

Comment: Any progress? Your problem solved?

Comment: @Ravan i would not say so. I changed terminal to Guake.

Comment: Can you try my answer and conform it? :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open terminal and run the command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open `compizconfig-settings-manager` , then

   General --> General Options --> Focus & Raise behaviour .

   Set `Focus Prevention Level` to **off**.

   [image: Imgur]

Comment: unfortunately I threw away elementary from my life, due to quite a lot of issues and not working software. But if somebody faces the same issue and accepts in comments, that your solution works - I will be glad to appreciate your try with upvote and choose it as a "right answer"

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to help. The newly created windows now always open in front of the other windows. The only minor annoyance is that they do not always have focus until clicked.

EDIT: I would post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.